# find the name of user executing the cron

Tags: php, linux, apache, cron

I've got a file index.php. there are 2 users having separate crons running accesing the scripts. is there any function in php/linux to identify which user's cron called that... its a cent-os..

Answer (score 1):

This returns the current user:

```
$user = exec('whoami');
```

http://php.net/manual/function.exec.php

Comment: nope.... the answer is apache in all cases.... since the php code is executed as apache user...

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

- Let the cronscript call the script directly, e.g. `php -f script.php`
- Let the cronscript specifify use user as a parameter, e.g. `wget http://host/script.php?user=$USER`

Answer (score 0):

- `$USER` environment variable
- `whoami` command

Comment: nope.... the answer is apache in all cases.... since the php code is executed as apache user

Comment: Please show what your cron entries look like. If you use `php -f`, this should not be the case.

Comment: no i use CURL function... in the cron. my cron script is like 

*/10 * * * * cron "example.com/index.php"

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass user info from your client (cronjob in this case). On server end php process is always run by webserver (apache in your case). So setup the cron to pass user something like: example.com/index.php?user=$USER and get this on server end as $_GET['user']